# Seam pages.xml exception handling don't redirect to error page

Tags: exception, seam

I have following are defined in seam's pages.xml

```
<page view-id="/view/Error.xhtml">
    <end-conversation before-redirect="true" root="true" />
</page>
<exception class="my.custom.exceptions.exception.BaseException">
    <redirect view-id="/view/Error.xhtml">
        <message severity="FATAL">Please contact system administrator.</message>
    </redirect>
</exception>
```

And following filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I've also disabled Facelets development mode in web.xml and Seam debug mode in components.xml

And in the user insert service class, I throws exception like following:

```
if(true) {throw new BaseException();}
```

However, it just print the BaseException at console instead of redirecting to error page. The page is still at user insert page. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've also tried annotations based exception handling. Here's the code.

```
@Redirect(viewId="/view/Error.xhtml", message="Unexpected error")
public class BaseException extends MyOwnRuntimeException {
```

Except from exceptions , other page redirections  defined in pages.xml are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated JBoss Seam library from version **2.3.0Final** to **2.3.1Final** and the problem is solved. Didn't even need to disable Facelets development mode and Seam debug mode even though Jboss doc said:

```
You need to disable Facelets development mode in web.xml and Seam debug mode
in components.xml if you want your exception handlers to fire.
```